# How to parse an XML String

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Am a newbie in Php and want to parse XML responses within a table in my PhpMyAdmin database, and after parsing them I would like to insert the response, which is a 16 digit number into a different table.

An example of an XML string am dealing with is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:sendSmsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/local"><ns1:result>1000022003011402
```

I have researched on how to parse XML strings through php and the above XML string can be parsed as follows:

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/local"><ns1:result>1000022003011402;
");
echo $xml->result() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->result() as $delivery_result)
  {
  echo $delivery_result->getResult() . ": " . $delivery_result . "<br>";
  }

?>
```

But am stuck on how to parse numerous strings within my PhpAdmin database, and insert the result into a diff table, just point me in the right direction i am sure i will get there.

This is how am logging into my database:

```
#set the connection

my $dbh =DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:NBKANGO', 'Kango', 'XXXXXXXXX') || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
```

Comment: Now that you have connected to the database, query the table that contains the xml strings, loop through them and use simplexml_load_string to create an xml object and extract the number you want.

Comment: @Robbert Thanks for the feedback, I can easily query the database but how do I go about looping through the result of the query, there is where am a bit stuck. Thanks

Comment: We're more than happy to help, but we're not going to write your code for you. A simple google for PDO query database should give you the answer to this. Try it, write some code and come back to SO with any problem you encounter.

Comment: @Robbert Thank You for the feedback, wasn't asking for the code to be pasted just to be pointed in the right direction which you have, Thank You!

Comment: Excellent. Google really is a programmer's best friend, whether you're starting out or a 20 year veteran.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do than within mysql you can try something like

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field,LOCATE('<ns1:result>', field),resultlength);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, could you kindly expound some more on that as am just learning how to code, Thanks!